# No output in C++ program while trying to make a rectangle

Tags: c++, bgi

I have just started graphics in C++ and was making a simple program to create a rectangle but no output screen is coming even though i have used getch(). can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int gm=0,gr=0;
    initgraph(&gm,&gr,"");
    cleardevice();
    rectangle(100,100,300,300);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Comment: Neither `graphics.h` nor `conio.h` are part of the c++ standard library.

Comment: so can you provide me with any alternate code.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-graphic-programming-in-c/

Comment: @AyushAgarwal There's no graphics support in the c++ standard, so no, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but it seems that you are trying to create a window with size 0.

There are diferent libraries based on the same, if it is correctly installed you can try:

```
int gm = 800, gr = 600;
initgraph(gm,gr,"name");
```

or

```
int gm = 800, gr = 600;
initwindow(gm,gr,"name");
```

or you can look at the graphics.h file and search the function there and its parameters.